# Problem transferring file to FTP server - 503 Could not create file

Tags: ftp, ssis, winscp

I try to transfer a file from SSIS package to a FTP server provided by my client. When I try connecting and transfer using a FTP tool (WinSCP) manually it works fine and file was transferred. But when i use the ftp command in command prompt and try to transfer using "send" command i get an error "553 could not create file". This also happens from SSIS package. I'm not in control of the FTP server but if anyone can provide a solution I can pass it to the admin or anything to be done from my end?

Comment: You might get more people to look at your question if you add more tags. Example of additional tags could be things like "error" or "SSIS" or "WinSCP" or even the specific error code.

Answer (score 1):

Did you command window authenticate to the FTP server with the same username/UID as WinSCP used?  Were you working in the same server directory?  Almost certainly you will find a difference in one or both of those items, and that difference will help show where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your firewall is not blocking active ftp connections.  WinSCP will default to using [passive connections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol#Protocol_overview) if it can't establish an active one, but the command line FTP can/will not.  Unfortunately, if active FTP connections are not supported from endpoint to endpoint (I.e. someone's firewall is blocking it), then you are dead in the water with the command line FTP...

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. It was because of a proxy server. I don't know how it works. But adding our network proxy server before trying to send the file in the FTP task of the SSIS package solved the issue. May be this small lead will help if anyone have the same issue in future.